# React Router V6.4 - Not rendering nested route element - instead render parents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am testing React Router v6.4 with [CreateBrowserRoute](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router)

Apparently, I'm running into a problem when I nest the routes deeper than 2 levels

**Router Object**

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <Root/>,
        children: [
            {
                index: true,
                element: <Index/>
            },
            {
                path: "tasks",
                element: <TaskIndex/>,
                children: [
                    {
                        index: true,
                        element: <TaskQue/>
                    },
                    {
                        path: "task-que",
                        element: <TaskQue/>,
                        children: [
                            {
                                path: "dashboard",
                                element: <TaskDashboard/>,
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                ]
            },
        ],
    },
]);
```

Basically, the path causing troubles is this path `tasks/task-que/dashboard` if I understand it all correctly it should map it like this `tasks->task-que->dashboard(element)` and then render the element set as the element key-value pair.

The route is working(ish), because if I remove the `path: "dashboard"` route and visit `tasks/task-que/dashboard` it will fail.

It seems a bit odd as it works very well in the second-level nesting.
If i change the parents element:

```
            path: "task-que",
            element: <TaskQue/>,
```

To

```
            path: "task-que",
            element: <TaskDashboard/>,
```

It will use TaskDashboard at both of these routes:

- `/tasks/task-que`
- `/tasks/task-que/dashboard`

Seems like I'm misunderstanding something or missing something, does anyone have any knowledge about deeper `react-router` nesting who can provide constructive tips or point out where I'm failing in my test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the `TaskQue` component is missing rendering an `Outlet` component for any nested routes ***it*** is wrapping. Each level of routing depth, if wrapping routes to nest them, still needs to render its own `Outlet` for the nested routes.

```
const TaskQue = () => {
  ... logic ...

  return (
    ... Task Queue UI JSX ...
    <Outlet /> // <-- "./dashboard" and <TaskDashboard />
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for your response. Yes, it might actually very well just be that I'm missing the outlet. I will check tomorrow at work thanks for the HU :)

Comment: If every step needs the outlet, it looks like each page will have its parent content rendered as well? Like now its rendering both the dashboard and taskque in the same page?

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 Affirmative. Each layout route necessarily needs to be rendered in order to also render the nested routes.

Comment: Well that is a problem in this project, however, your answer is accepted as it is the correct answer.

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 If you want to render say a dashboard component and a taskque component separately then you can omit the `element` prop on the layout route (*an `Outlet` will be rendered by default*) and move the dashboard component into a nested `index` route.